# Trying to create multiple AD users at once using CSV and Powershell. Splatting appears to be causing issues

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As the title says, I'm trying to use powershell in combination with a CSV file to create multiple users at once but keep encountering an error. I have included the error and my code below. Any help in fixing this is much appreciated!

Powershell Error:

```
New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax
At line:32 char:17
+             } } New-ADUser @hash
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Test User...REFORM,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Powershell Code:

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv EnterFilePathHere

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{

       $Firstname   = $User.firstname
       $Surname    = $User.surname
       $Password    = $User.password
       $OU          = $User.ou
       $Description = $User.description
       $Email       = $User.email
       $Username    = -join("$Firstname", "_", "$Surname") 

         
            $hash = @{
                SamAccountName = $Username
                UserPrincipalName = "$Username@EnterDomainHere"
                Name = "$($User.firstName) $($User.surName)"
                givenName = $FirstName
                surName = $Surname
                Enabled = $true
                ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
                DisplayName = "$FirstName $Surname"
                Path = $OU
                Description = $Description
                EmailAddress = $Email
                AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "$Password" -AsPlainText -Force)
              
            } New-ADUser @hash      
}
```

As mentioned by theo, New-ADUser @hash is currently outside of the loop. Frustratingly, when I move it up a line (as I now have in the code displayed above) I am faced with another error:

```
            
At line:32 char:15
+             } New-AdUser @hash }
+               ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'New-AdUser' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

[Here's an example of the CSV file as displayed in Excel. The file is saved as CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hltxR.png)

Comment: Move the `New-ADUser` line up one line. Now it is placed **after** the loop

Comment: Mmm, that was my first thought, too. Unfortunately when I tried that, it came up with the following error: At line:32 char:15
+             } New-AdUser @hash }
+               ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'New-AdUser' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Well, then you should show us part of the csv file (sanitized names) so we can see what we're dealing with. Is that file _comma_ delimited?

Comment: I've added an example entry from the CSV file to my post for your reference, Theo. Yes the file is comma delimited.

Comment: I guess it happened while sanitizing, but the ou is missing a comma. However, that is not what the error is saying., On mobile now, so I can't check in an editor, but it looks like the New-ADUser line is now not **below** the closing bracket of the hash, but directly following in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to indent better, then you will spot the error soon enough. The `New-ADUser` cmdlet should be on its own separate line right below the closing bracket of the Hashtable.

Also, you don't need all those variables, just a few to make things easier

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path '<EnterFilePathHere>'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    # for convenience create some variables that will be used more often
    $Firstname = $User.firstname
    $Surname   = $User.surname
    $Username  = '{0}_{1}' -f $Firstname, $Surname
    # create the splatting Hashtable
    $hash = @{
        SamAccountName        = $Username
        UserPrincipalName     = "$Username@EnterDomainHere"
        Name                  = "$Firstname $Surname"
        GivenName             = $FirstName
        Surname               = $Surname
        DisplayName           = "$FirstName $Surname"
        Enabled               = $true
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        Path                  = $User.ou
        Description           = $User.description
        EmailAddress          = $User.email
        AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.password -AsPlainText -Force)
    } 
    New-ADUser @hash      
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working :-) I appreciate that massively. Still very new to coding/powershell, so simple things like this frequently trip me up, haha.